# How to get the percentage of quantity inside the <td> tag?

Tags: vue.js

I want to get the percentage of quantity per day. I'm using methods to get the sum of all the quantity. The problem when I combined it to `distributed.Quantity` like this `<td>{{distributed.Quantity / sumAllOfQuantity() * 100 | twoDecimal}}</td>`. I get a NaN value. How can I compute the percentage of quantity per day.

HTML

```
<thead class="thead-info">
   <tr>
     <th>Avg. Qty / Day</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody v-if="distributed_per_day.length > 0">
   <tr v-for="(distributed, index) in distributed_per_day">
     <td>{{distributed.Quantity / sumAllOfQuantity() * 100 | twoDecimal}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Methods

```
sumAllOfQuantity : function() {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.distributed_per_day.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(this.distributed_per_day[i].Quantity);
    }
},
```

Filter

```
twoDecimal(value) {
   return value.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `sumAllOfQuantity` is not returning a value you can either add `return  sum` on your function / add the `parseInt` to the `distributed.Quantity` on the template or use a computed property for the total quantity which i recommend rather than a method that gets called multiple times:

```js
computed : {
  totalQuantity() {
    return this.distributed_per_day.reduce((acc,val)=> acc + parseInt(val.Quantity),0)
  }
}
```

```html
<tr v-for="(distributed, index) in distributed_per_day">
   <td>{{ parseInt(distributed.Quantity) / totalQuantity * 100 | twoDecimal}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use computed property like this:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    distributed_per_day: [
      { Quantity: 1 },
      { Quantity: 2 },
      { Quantity: 3 }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    sumAllOfQuantity() {
      return this.distributed_per_day.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.Quantity, 0)
    }
  },
  filters: {
    twoDecimal(value) {
      return value.toFixed(2);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead class="thead-info">
     <tr>
       <th>Avg. Qty / Day</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody v-if="distributed_per_day.length > 0">
       <tr v-for="(distributed, index) in distributed_per_day">
         <td>{{(distributed.Quantity / sumAllOfQuantity * 100) | twoDecimal}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```